# How to Get 3 Branches for Each Category in Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a places table that has a category_id as a foreign key and branches belong to Place in my model.

I want to get exactly 3 branches for each category_id from each place

I tried the below query but its still returning a place lets say id 2 and 3 having the same category_id it will return both with even more than 3 branches.

How can i modify it to make it only return 3 branches for each place for only the categories i specify?

Heres my query:

```
$places = Place::select(
                'places.id as place_id',
                'places.name',
                'places.description',
                'places.tags as place_tags',
                'branches.id as branch_id',
                'branches.name as branch_name',
                'categories.id as category_id',
                'categories.name')
                ->leftJoin('branches', 'places.id', '=', 'branches.place_id')
                ->leftJoin('categories', 'categories.id', '=', 'places.category_id')
                ->whereIn('places.category_id', [1, 2, 3])
                
                ->get();
```

Comment: So you want all places for the given categories? And for each place you want 3 branches? What are the criteria for which 3 branches to select per place? Adding some sample data and your desired output may help explain what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: What MySQL version are you using?

Answer (score -1):

For this you can use laravel relationship instead of leftjoin.

Define it in the place model:

```
function getBranchData() {  
    return $this->hasMany(Branch::class, 'place_id', 'id') -> limit(3);
}
```